# How to fix "module not found error" in xhr2-cookies

Tags: angular, http, https, xmlhttprequest, angular-cli

I have my code written using angular CLI 7.3.1 and when i try to build using `ng build` i am getting the following error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/User/Desktop/fy_project_blockchain/angularSwarm/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/User/Desktop/fy_project_blockchain/angularSwarm/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'
```

I have tried removing xhr2-cookies and re-installing it. Also i have tried installing http https module, giving the path for the modules in the `xml-http-request.js` file but it still gives me the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Add This in your `package.json` file

```
  "browser": {
    "http": false,
    "https": false,
    "os": false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`import * as Cookie from 'cookiejar';
XMLHttpRequest.cookieJar = Cookie.CookieJar();`

Used above like

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Tried this, but it still gives the same error

Comment: where you import cookiejar?

Comment: inside ```xml-http-request.js``` file which is inside dist folder of xhr2-cookies