# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in './node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist' while using react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web3js, truffle

I was working on a truffle project with react in the front-end. As I was importing web3 to my App.js, this happens,

> ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 41:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in
> './node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

along with seven more errors like

> Can't resolve 'crypto'
> Can't resolve 'http'

etc.
I already tried the solutions provided here>
[How to fix "module not found error" in xhr2-cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56216271/how-to-fix-module-not-found-error-in-xhr2-cookies)

My package.json file is as follows:

```
    {
  "name": "bootcamp-new",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.4.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^2.0.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.33.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset": "^1.1.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chai-bignumber": "^3.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "dotenv": "^12.0.3",
    "eth-lib": "^0.1.29",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-gyp": "^8.4.1",
    "openzeppelin-solidity": "^4.4.2",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "reselect": "^4.1.5",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.7.17",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "truffle": "^5.4.29",
    "truffle-flattener": "^1.5.0",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider-privkey": "^0.3.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3",
    "web3": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1" 
  }
}
```

and my webpack.config.js file is:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");


module.exports = {
  
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
      process: "process/browser",
    }),
  ],
  resolve:{
    fallback: {
      http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
      https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
      crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      os: require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),  
      url: require.resolve("url"),
      assert: require.resolve("assert"), 
    },
  }
}
```

But still getting the errors. Some guys told me to upgrade babel and I did. But, no luck.

Comment: Have you tried first deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and doing an npm install?